# What title or term is appropriate for a genuine or sincere person?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What title or term is appropriate for a genuine or sincere person?

I'm looking to avoid using the terms "genuine," "sincere," and "honest" as adjectives. I would like to use a noun that implies these characteristics.

For example: I can potentially call a person who is highly dogmatic a priest.
Far easier than that, I could call a protective person a defender.

For context: I am presently writing my wedding vows. I would like to communicate to my future husband that I vow to be his (TERM IN QUESTION HERE), and then add some strong but expressive context to the statement.

Comment: Can you please give an example sentence showing how the word would be used? A 'title' is usually a formal way of addressing someone, or a name that describes someone's position or job.

Comment: The original question has been edited for context. 

Unfortunately, I don't have the sentence structured yet, as I am awaiting the term in question. 

I could provide another example of what I mean, however. Please see the below quote from another portion of the vows. 

"I vow to ever be your defender, your protector, and your confidant; whatever time and circumstance might bring. No danger shall find you alone."

Comment: I was about to suggest confidante, but there you have it in your own example.

Comment: A good word - thank you for responding.

Comment: *I vow to be true* No, not me, I'm a slippery kind of character, I mean OP might incorporate that in <appropriate pronoun> wedding vows.

Comment: You may be able to sum up several of your adjectives with other evocative adjective, for example *your stalwart, ..., confidante*. *Stalwart* is "marked by oustanding strength and vigor of body,  mind, or spirit." (m-w)

Comment: I enjoy "stalwart," thank you.

Comment: I seem to be unable to award you all with votes due to my rank/level on this site. 
Thank you all, nonetheless.

Comment: I will be your **rock**.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to turn to metaphor. "Genuine, sincere, and honest": someone who doesn't hide or lie about their true feelings. "An open book" is a common idiom. A "plumb line" is something that can be relied on for accuracy. If the point is that your husband can trust you to tell him the truth about himself without flattery or prevarication, some poetic turn of phrase like "your unclouded mirror" might be appropriate.

Comment: I love the idea of using the expression *I vow to be your plumb line* in one's wedding vows!  Me, I'd throw in *and your spirit level* too, but maybe that's too much?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark “Your spirited levelness is my spirit’s spirit level, and raises the level of my spirits.”

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark “You are my set square, without whom all my right angles would be just wrong—and I’d be obtuse not to note that you’re pretty acute, too…”

Comment: I want to marry you ...